# CoreFoundation/ UIKit crash in iOS 15 app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, ios15

Since update to iOS 15, our app is crashing in the first controller, right after splash screen(log attached).

To be mentioned that if app goes to background right after being active, it will only crash after i switch it back in foreground.

At crash it gets me right to int main() without any relevant info to help me debug, except (maybe) this line in the console "[Unknown process name] CGBitmapContextCreateWithCallbacks: failed to create CGAutomaticBitmapContextInfo."

I've tried using all exceptions breakpoint but didn't help debugging further. It seems to be an issue in storyboard and not a specific line of code.

At start, the app has a tabBarController which integrates some controllers. The first goes like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews, viewDidLayoutSubviews and then dies before reaching viewDidAppear.

Would appreciate some help

**LATER UPDATE:**

After isolating the UI almost like a standard user, I found out that the TabBarController was the problem. No matter what background picture i'd set, either from storyboard or from the controller class, the app would crash once it would instantiate the tabbar controller. As the tabbar had a background image already, there we go with the 5/5 crash after update. Very strange

```
Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001857c38b0 CFRetain.cold.1 + 16 (CFRuntime.c:986)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185653a80 CFRetain + 144 (CFRuntime.c:986)
2   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187aa9f44 __58-[_UIImageContent renditionWithSize:scale:applyingEffect:]_block_invoke.96 + 32 (_UIImageContent.m:354)
3   UIKitCore                       0x0000000188b32bfc -[UIImageView _renditionForSource:size:symbolConfiguration:withCGImageProvider:lazy:] + 1632 (UIImageView.m:718)
4   UIKitCore                       0x0000000188b319cc -[_UIImageContentLayoutWeakEffect _renditionForSource:size:symbolConfiguration:withCGImageProvider:lazy:] + 140 (UIImageView.m:146)
5   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187b233bc -[_UIImageContentContextualEffect _renditionWithCGImageProvider:size:lazy:] + 44 (_UIImageContentEffect.m:34)
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187eb1c90 -[_UIImageContent renditionWithSize:scale:applyingEffect:] + 820 (_UIImageContent.m:361)
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187fbcb94 -[_UIImageContent renditionApplyingEffect:] + 112 (_UIImageContent.m:252)
8   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187b1c124 -[_UIImageContentLayout _materializeContentsIfNeeded] + 68 (_UIImageContentLayout.m:578)
9   UIKitCore                       0x0000000187ca6ba4 -[_UIImageContentLayout contents] + 20 (_UIImageContentLayout.m:592)
10  UIKitCore                       0x0000000187bc0914 -[UIImageView _handlePendingImageLayout:] + 72 (UIImageView.m:487)
11  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189177e5c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 424 (CALayer.mm:2445)
12  QuartzCore                      0x000000018918b4a4 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 496 (CAContextInternal.mm:2584)
13  QuartzCore                      0x000000018919408c CA::Transaction::commit() + 660 (CATransactionInternal.mm:449)
14  UIKitCore                       0x0000000187af4bc0 _afterCACommitHandler + 84 (UIApplication.m:3003)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185675f34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1804)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185647578 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 588 (CFRunLoop.c:1917)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185642b0c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012 (CFRunLoop.c:2979)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185655d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
19  GraphicsServices                0x000000019f7629a0 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2200)
20  UIKitCore                       0x0000000187e8b018 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080 (UIApplication.m:3457)
21  UIKitCore                       0x0000000187c1f29c UIApplicationMain + 2060 (UIApplication.m:5013)
22  trust4mobile                    0x0000000100b34d20 main + 88 (main.m:14)
23  dyld                            0x000000010128c190 start + 444 (dyldMain.cpp:876)
```

Comment: Maybe you've got an image view whose image is missing, or something like that?

Comment: I would start setting breakpoints inside the "view lifecycle" methods of all those tab-bar controllers (`viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, et al) and see how far you make it before crashing. This should allow you to find the responsible controller. From there, start unsetting the `image` property of all the UIImageViews that controller owns, one by one, until you no longer crash. Then figure out what's different about that particular UIImageView. Swap in a different image and see if you crash again.

Comment: After isolating the UI almost like a standard user, I found out that the TabBarController was the problem. No matter what background picture i'd set, either from storyboard or from the controller class, the app would crash once it would instantiate the tabbar controller. As the tabbar had a background image already, there we go with the 5/5 crash after update. Very strange